# Associate with file type

Tags: file, pycharm

I accidentally changed the "Chrome" file type to txt from exe and it displays the gibberish text. I want it to be like the geckodriver.exe

I am not able to revert it back to its original format. any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to do this. You need to go to Settings > Editor > File Types, then select the exe file type from the Recognized File Types list on top, and then remove the .chrome file type from the Registered Patterns list.